# How many environmental variables do I need for Python on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, python, environment-variables

I just added python38 path to the environmental variable, and was downloading numpy module using pip command, a warning showed up saying

"The script chardetect.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\utkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location."

I added the same mentioned to the PATH. And now i am wondering, are 2 paths for python even required?

Answer (score 0):

> How many environmental variables do I need for Python on Windows 10?

None, unless a specific third-party module requires it or you wish to access certain Python-related executables from the command line without typing their full path (ex. `python.exe` itself or any executable installed or created by a third-party module).

> Are two paths for Python even required?

As a practical matter, while not required, adding the `Scripts` folder for your primary Python installation to your Windows environment is something I would generally recommend. Without it, executables installed or created by Python modules may not be accessible in certain instances (since this is where they live by default).

In your case, `chardetect.exe` resides in `Scripts` and the warning you were given was letting you know that there may have been issues if access to `chardetect.exe` was required (since it was not in your Windows path).